# selenium-webdriver npm wait

Tags: node.js, selenium

I have a simple script that performs a login using the selenium-webdriver npm module.  The script works, but it is really slow and the wait timeout is giving very odd results (sometimes it seems to timeout immediately, and other times it waits far past the defined timeout).

Am I doing something wrong that would make the login very slow (running this through a selenium hub perhaps)?  The site itself is very responsive.

Here is the script:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    usingServer('http://hubserver:4444/wd/hub').
    withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
    build();

console.log('\n\nStarting login.');
console.log('\nConnecting to grid: http://hubserver:4444/wd/hub' );

// Load the login page and wait for the form to display
driver.get('https://testsite.com');
driver.wait(function() {
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name('user'));

}, 3000, '\nFailed to load login page.');

// Enter the user name
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('user')).sendKeys('testuser').then(function() {
    console.log("\nEntering user name");
});

// Enter the password
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('pass')).sendKeys('testpwd').then(function() {
    console.log("\nEntering password");
});

// Click the login button
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('submit')).click().then(function() {
    console.log("\nLogging in.");
});

// Wait for the home page to load
driver.wait(function() {
    console.log("\nWaiting for page to load");
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.id('main'));
}, 3000, '\nFailed to load home page.');

driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    console.log("\nPage loaded: " + url);
});
driver.quit();
```

Comment: You don't set an implicit wait anywhere do you? (Some people don't put in their SO questions the *exact* code they are using. So I'm not assuming anything.) Also, can you try driving your browser directly, without going through a hub, and see if the strange timing issues go away? (I've just noticed the date on your post... maybe you've solved it already and can post an answer?)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you have it specified elsewhere, but in the code shown your `driver.wait()` has no amount of time specified.

Also, maybe I'm misunderstanding your code because I do this mainly in Python, but `driver.wait(function(){});` looks weird to me. Is this really proper use of the JS bindings? Generally, you wait for the element to be found and then subsequently call a function that does something with the element. I can't write it in JS, but in pseudocode:

```
driver.wait(#element you're looking for)
# Handle exception if there is one
# Otherwise do something with element you're looking for
```

Also, I would think

```
driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name('user'));
```

Should be

```
driver.isElementPresent(By.name('user'));
```